# C# Make item show

Tags: c#, button, progress-bar, hidden

I am trying to hide a progress bar until a button is clicked. Once the button is clicked I would like the progress bar to show. How would I do that? I am new to C#.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- In the form view, on your progress bar properties, make sure that the "Visible" property is set to false.

2- Create a click event for the button (you can double click it in the form view, it will generate the event).

3- In the click event function, set your progress bar visibility to true. (YourProgressBarID.Visible = true)  and you might want to hide that button, you could use YourButtonID.Visible = false

Answer (score 0):

During the initialization of your form, set the visibility of your ProgressBar to `false` or set it in from the [`Designer Properties`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8LdK.png).

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    progressBar1.Visible = false;
}
```

Now, on your button click event just make the visibility of your ProgressBar to `true`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Visible = true;
}
```